# SSMS query to Excel w/o formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a query whose result is as follows:

Take note of the PrimaryIdentifier value.

[image]

Whenever I export it to an excel file or even copy it to an excel file. It looks like:

[image]

Is there anyway I can export it or copy to the excel as is, w/o formatting?

Changing the format in Excel to text does not resolve the issue.

Is there any change that can be done to the query itself so that I get the desired o/p in the excel? Clearly the primary identifier column need to be 145231E44  and not 1.45E+49!

Answer (score 1):

Format the column as text before pasting the values, if you try to do this after pasting then it is too late because the value has already changed.

If you cannot do this then in the query you could prepend the value with an "X" so that it is treated as text. Unfortunately, you cannot then just use the Replace feature of Excel to remove the "X" as it, on testing, will be reverted to a number.

You could insert a column and format it as text,

```
Range("B1:B200").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Then get the values into B, from A, with the X's removed:

```
Range("B1").Value = Mid(Range("A1").Value, 2, 255)
```

Comment: My requirement is to directly import the query results to an excel without any formatting done to the excel file. Is this possible, with doing some changes in the query itself?

Comment: I've added a suggestion to my answer, but you might wait for a better suggestion, as mine is a bit involved. Personally, I'm not sure that it can be achieved any more easily.

Answer (score 0):

MS-Access is an excellent conduit between SQL Server and Excel.

Link the SQL table to Access so you can create a query (I'm calling it "Export_Query") to get all the fields you need from the SQL Server table.

Use the function `TransferSpreadsheet` function to copy from the query to Excel:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
                          acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                          "Export_Query", _
                          "C:\temp\excel.xlsx", _
                          True
```

The Excel workbook must exist in the location you specify. As long as your `PrimaryIdentifier` is defined as a string data type (I used `varchar`) you should get the correct result in the excel file.

My test table looks like this in SQL Server:

[image: source table in excel]

and the result in Excel looks like this:

[image: Excel data]

Answer (score 0):

The work around to my question is:

Wrapping the parameter (PrimaryIdentifier) in the select clause with ="[PrimaryIdentifier]"

Ex: SELECT '="' +PrimaryIdentifier+ '"' FROM .... WHERE ...

This makes sure the query result stays in the same format in the excel sheet while copying or exporting.